Period or semicolon after short description
Load: At least 10ft long. At least 5kg.
If I want to list details of something without using bullets in order to save space, is it  weird to use periods as above? How about semicolons?
e.g., Load: At least 10ft long; At least 5kg.

IMO a comma is good: At least 10ft long, at least 5kg.

Ok! Thank you!!

I wouldn't use the fullstop or semicolon.  Neither will I use the capital letter for at as there are no complete sentences.  We may consider
Load: at least 10ft long, at least 5kg

Thank you. No period at the end is better?

As there’re no complete sentences,  we don't use the fullstop.

Ok! I got it. Thanks
